# Electron: How do I populate a menu from a render process?

Tags: menu, electron

I would like to create a menu of favourite or recently opened documents for an Electron application. I can easily track these documents once they have been opened, but how can I dynamically add them to a menu?

What I have learned so far:

- Create an menu in the main process:

  ```
  menu=[
      {
          label: 'Some Application',
          submenu: [
              {   label: `Open …`, accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+O', id:'OPEN', click: send },
              {   label: `Documents …`, id:'DOCUMENTS', click: send, submenu: [] },
              {   type:'separator' },
              {   role: `quit`, accelerator: 'CmdOrCtrl+Q' }
          ]
      },
  ];
  ```
- Use `remote` in the render process:

  ```
  const electron=require('electron');
  const { ipcRenderer, shell, remote } = electron;
  const {app,BrowserWindow,dialog,Menu,MenuItem}=remote;
  ```

I have the documents in a JSON file, but I don’t know what to do next to add them to the `Documents` menu above.

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking into this "recently" ;-).

It is a built in feature: [feat: Recent documents menu item #11166](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/11166)

```
 {
      label: 'Open Recent',
      role: 'recentdocuments',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Clear Recent',
          role: 'clearrecentdocuments'
        }
      ]
    },
```

And [app.addRecentDocument(path)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appaddrecentdocumentpath-macos-windows) and [app.clearRecentDocuments()](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appclearrecentdocuments-macos-windows) can be used.  Electron 8 adds this feature: [dontAddToRecent to Windows showOpenDialog](https://github.com/electron/electron/pull/19669)

I've been able to get it working on `macOS` though I haven't been able to figure out how to do the [Application Registration](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/recent-documents#windows-notes) thing yet (through `electron-builder`, I guess) which is required to get it working on `Windows`.

I also saw the code snippet below from [here](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4028#issuecomment-255495185) but I haven't had a chance to test it yet. Also, be aware that `remote` is going to be deprecated in Electron 9: [Deprecate the 'remote' module and move it to userland](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/21408)

---

```
function updateRecents(path, clear = false) {
  const currentMenu = Menu.getApplicationMenu();
  if (!currentMenu) return;

  const recents = getItemByKey(currentMenu, 'recents');
  if (!recents) return;

  // Clear menu if requested.
  if (clear) {
    config.set('recentDocuments', []);
    recents.submenu.clear();
    recents.submenu.append(new MenuItem({ key: 'null', label: 'No Recent Documents', enabled: false }));
    Menu.setApplicationMenu(currentMenu);
    return;
  }

  const item = new MenuItem({
    label: require('path').basename(path),
    click: () => this.open(path)
  });

  // If first recent item clear empty placeholder.
  if (recents.submenu.items[0].key == 'null') {
    recents.submenu.clear();
    recents.submenu.append(item);
  }
  // Limit to maximum 10 recents.
  else if (recents.submenu.items.length >= 10) {
    const items = recents.submenu.items;
    recents.submenu.clear();
    items.push(item);
    items.slice(10).forEach((i) => recents.submenu.append(i));
  }
  // Otherwise just add item.
  else recents.submenu.append(item);

  // Update application menu.
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(currentMenu);
}
```